# Force a no_cache link with <n:link

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.1.x, tx-news

Is it somehow possible to force a no_cache link with tx_news?

```
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{no_cache:1}" uriOnly="1"/>
```

The link should look like this:

http://domain.com/**no_cache**/articleurl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable caching for your news item, you can set the no_cache on your page.

you can also take a look at the viewhelper class of tx_news to see if this is possible. If not, you can add an additional parameter yourself